# How to abort build via shell script in Jenkins within if else condition

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So I am trying my hands with Jenkins file condition within stages of build but unable to achieve the results as expected. So I want to fail a build and stop execution of next stages if failures exist in the smoke / sanity tests. This can be found only if the console has "FailedCount 0"

Here is my script:

```
    stage('Run main tests') {
      when {
        expression {
           // some expression
        }
      }
      
      steps {
// some step which runs a test module
                sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''#!/bin/bash
                           if [[ ${stdout} != *"FailedCount 0"* ]];then
 currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
 echo "ABORTING the JOB because of failures"
  fi
                '''.stripIndent())
      }

    }
```

but I am receiving this error in console with status of that stage success and the next stage also continues to execute.

```
durable-dde00bfa/script.sh: line 4: currentBuild.result: command not found
```

Could someone please help me out to see what I am doing wrong?

PS:
This is what I am asserting on within the if condition
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't set Jenkins variables from within the shell script. If you want to simply `Fail` the build you can exit the shell script with exit code 1.

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''#!/bin/bash
     if [[ ${stdout} != *"FailedCount 0"* ]];then
         echo "ABORTING the JOB because of failures"
         exit 1
     fi
'''.stripIndent())
```

If you wan to `Abort` the build you can do something like below. Get the output of the shell script and check for the Abort message.

```
stage('Run main tests') {
  when {
    expression {
       // some expression
    }
  }  
    steps {
        script {
            // some step which runs a test module
            def output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''#!/bin/bash
                           if [[ ${stdout} != *"FailedCount 0"* ]];then
                            echo "ABORTING the JOB because of failures"
                           fi
                '''.stripIndent())
            if (output.contains("ABORTING the JOB because of failures")) {
                currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                error('Aborting the Build')
            }
        }
  }
}
```

---

**Update:** Checking the console out and failing the build.

```
script {
  def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text
  if(!consoleLog.contains("FailedCount 0")){
     error('Failing due to test failures')
  } else {
    echo "No Failures detected"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to Fail the build so used the first code segment. But I got this error in Jenkins console "line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `1'
line 4: `                 exit(1)'"

Comment: @neyrah sorry my bad. The syntax was wrong. Check the updated answer.

Comment: This works but it fails the build no matter "FailedCount 0" exists or not within the console. Maybe the if else condition is missing something? I have added screenshot in my question of what I am trying to search from console

Comment: @neyrah are you trying to read the Jenkins console?

Comment: yes. I am checking from Jenkins console

Comment: This seems to work but I will need the Jenkins admin to approve this library. Will do so and see if its successful. Thanks!